# Getting dynamic objects to match baked lighting on nearby static objects

Tags: unity, lighting

Here's how the hallway in my game looks now:

[image]

You might notice the dark section near the centre of the screen; This is, in fact, a pair of cupboard doors which are not set to static and so don't get included in the baked lighting.

The problem is, since all of my house lights are baked only, it looks like the only light these doors are getting is the ambient light - so quite dark.

Is there an alternative, best practise to ensure non-static objects get lit sufficiently when lighting is baked?

Comment: I think Light Probe Group might be helpful. Try read this: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-LightProbeGroup.html

Comment: That did, indeed, do the trick! Thanks! Feel free to add your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically Dynamic object doesn't include when baking lights. To solve this, Unity provides [Light Probe Group](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-LightProbeGroup.html), capture the light information passing through the empty space, will use to nearest dynamic objects.